# Call different methods by type in Java

Tags: java, generics, overloading

```
private void foo(int a, int b) {
  // do something
  System.out.println(add(a, b));
  // do something else
}

private void bar(String a, String b) {
  // do something
  System.out.println(add(a, b));
  // do something else
}

private int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

private String add(String a, String b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}
```

Is it possible to merge duplicated logic in foo and bar into one function?

e.g.

```
private <T> void baz(T a, T b) {
  // do something
  System.out.println(add(a, b));
  // do something else
}
```

-- EDIT --

Just tried to put a simple example to describe my question.

Actually in my real code I don't need the return type, the functions are like following:

```
void func(Integer a);
void func(String a);
void func(MyEnum a);
void func(MyClass a);
void func(List<MyClass> a);
```

And I'd like to have a function like:

```
private <T> void baz(T a) {
  // do something
  func(a);
  // do something else
}
```

So I don't have to write the same logic multiple times.

Comment: You can add a parameter `Consumer<T>` and replace `func(a);` with `consumer.accept(a);`, then, the caller must provide a reference to the appropriate `func` method, `baz(42, this::func);` will use `func(Integer)`, `baz("test", this::func);` will use `func(String)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your `baz` code is valid, but won't work for your case because generic parameters get reduced to `Object` at runtime, so it needs to be resolved at compile time. To be able to do that, you'd need a common interface like `Addable`, then you could declare it

```
private <T extends Addable> void baz(T a, T b) {
  // do something
  System.out.println(add(a, b));
  // do something else
}
```

but you wouldn't be able to call it with `int` or `String` because those don't implement `Addable`; you could wrap them, but not much gained in what you're trying to do.

So in short: no, not possible; you need to design around this.

```
interface Addable<T extends Addable<T>> { T add(T to Add); }

class IntAddable implements Addable<IntAddable> {
  Integer value;
  Integer add(IntAddable toAdd { 
    return new IntAddable(value + to Add.value);
 }
}
IntAddable a = new IntAddable(1);
IntAddable b = new IntAddable(2);
IntAddable sum = baz(a, b);
// assuming an analogue class for String
StringAddable concatted = baz(s1, s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this as you've written it.

The biggest blocker (as I see it) is that add(String,String) returns an object, but add(int,int) returns a primative(int), so there's a problem with return type.

But I think you are over complicating things here. Why can't the two add functions could stand on their own? Do you really need a generic `baz` function?

Comment: Is it possible if the return type is `void`? Just updated my question.